# Can I have a list of opened windows instead expo effect?

Tags: launcher, unity-2d

When there are more than one window opened of the same aplication and I click on the icon to choose between the windows, the expo effect appears, just like the image below:

[image: example one]

But in Unity 2D it gets slow, so I would like to have a list instead, something like that:

[image: example two]
[image: example tree]

Is it possible? If yes, how to do that? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I've come across for configuring Unity 2D is dconf-tolls which is mentioned [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/things-to-tweak-after-installing-ubuntu.html) (see the Unity 2D section) but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any way to accomplish what you're trying to do. The options available to Unity 2D are very basic - essentially just things like when the panel should hide, whether or not the super key works with it, and so on. This is mostly due to the newness of Unity (in particular Unity 2D) and should get better as it matures.